# Connecting to WPA2 network from console

Tags: network-manager, encryption, networking, console

How can I connect to a WPA2 Encrypted Network from the Terminal/Console?

I've wanted to remove the whole x-window system and use a Terminal based system only to free up any available memory and process list(s), but the only way to I have to connect to my ESSID network right now is via the Network Manager.

One other thing of note is that the *wpa-supplicant* is currently not working for my Zydas USB card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cli to networkmanager called [cnetworkmanager](http://vidner.net/martin/software/cnetworkmanager/) or [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/) which also has command line utility and gtk is just optional. I think wicd uses wpa_supplicant.

Answer (score 2):

This works, if you can keep X around, but just don't want to use it, and want your system to connect to wireless without starting X.

Start X and use *nm-applet* to conncet to your wireless. Then bring up context menu of *nm-applet* and choose *Edit connections*. Choose *Wirelless* tab, select your connection and *Edit*. Now mark the *Available to all users* checkbox. Authorize this action with your password and *Save*.

Now after reboot your system should automatically connect to the wireless without logging into X.

Comment: Can I remove X without losing auto connecting during boot time?

Comment: Sure, You are free to remove X, of course while you don't need to add a new wireless connection :)

Comment: And after I wrote this answer I remembered wicd as @sagarchalise mentions in his answer. wicd has nice curses interface - install package "wicd-curses". However in my experience wicd is slower to connect than network-manager. 
Furthermore You cannot run wicd and network-manager simultaneously, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could install a lightweight window manager like LXDE.
if you want to connect to a wifi network without graphical environment
you should learn about the iwconfig and iwlist and then
use the iw wlan0 connect command to connect to your wifi network.